# Streamlit image loop

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

Can someone help me to make this a loop or it can be a loop? I just wanted to check whether it can be loop or not.

```py
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7 = st.beta_columns(7)

with c1:
    fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig1.suptitle("Gray Eqhist")
    plt.imshow(gray_eqhist, 'gray')        
    st.pyplot(fig1)
with c2:
    fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig2.suptitle("Applied Clahe")
    plt.imshow(applied_clahe, 'gray')        
    st.pyplot(fig2)
with c3:
    fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig3.suptitle("Binary")
    plt.imshow(thresh1, 'gray')        
    st.pyplot(fig3)
with c4:
    fig4 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig4.suptitle("Binary Threshold Inverted")
    plt.imshow(thresh2, 'gray')        
    st.pyplot(fig4)
with c5:
    fig5 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig5.suptitle("Truncated Threshold")
    plt.imshow(thresh3, 'gray')        
    st.pyplot(fig5)
with c6:
    fig6 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig6.suptitle("Set to 0")
    plt.imshow(thresh4, 'gray')        
    st.pyplot(fig6)
with c7:
    fig7 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig7.suptitle("Set to 0 Inverted")
    plt.imshow(thresh5, 'gray')        
    st.pyplot(fig7)
```

Comment: You can iterate through other variables, like maybe your graph and labels and do something like this example of a table: `for i in range(1, 10):
    cols = st.beta_columns(4)
    cols[0].write(f'{i}')
    cols[1].write(f'{i * i}')
    cols[2].write(f'{i * i * i}')
    cols[3].write('x' * i)`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Try this.

```py
configurations = [dict(title = "Gray Eqhist",               image = gray_eqhist),
                  dict(title = "Applied Clahe",             image = applied_clahe),
                  dict(title = "Binary",                    image = thresh1),
                  dict(title = "Binary Threshold Inverted", image = thresh2),
                  dict(title = "Truncated Threshold",       image =  thresh3),
                  dict(title = "Set to 0",                  image = thresh4),
                  dict(title = "Set 0 to Invernted",        image = thresh5)]


columns = st.beta_columns(len(configurations))

for column, configuration in zip(columns, configurations):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    fig.suptitle(configuration["title"])
    plt.imshow(configuration["image"], 'gray')
    column.pyplot(fig)
```

you can usually replace `st` with the column name like `c1`. `st` is a reference to the main page. `c1` is a reference to a subsection. So you can do `c1.text("Hello World")` without the `with` block.

Comment: Thank youu for your answerr, very much appreciated. Can I request I question?

Comment: Sure. What's your question? (Next time you have a question, just ask the question.It's simpler that way)